# (Gtk) can I create a very large treeview without performance problems?

Tags: c++, c, treeview, gtk

in my Gtk application I use a `Gtk::TreeView` which stores many rows - from a few hundred to 2000 or more. I can not notice any performance issues with this, I can scroll it and use it without problems. My question is, will this also be true in general, e.g. on weaker computers? The Treeview is embedded in a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow`.

Would appreciate any info on this :)

regards, tagelicht

Comment: 2000 rows? its no big deal.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-fixed-height-mode)?

Comment: No I didnt know this yet thanks again :)

Comment: 2000 rows is small enough to be doable, and how GtkTreeView manages memory is up to it. I'm sure it's fast enough, though. If using GtkListStore wastes memory, you can always implement your own GtkTreeModel.

Comment: Were You able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I did not notice any problems with the TreeView, even when well above 2000 rows. This is probably dependent on the user's machine, but its performance seems to be very good. Theoretically, I could have implemented paging by loading the treeview with a fixed amount of rows and allow the user to switch between pages by reloading the treeview.